# Angularjs not rendering

Tags: angularjs

I downloaded a sample Angular app from

```
https://github.com/angular/material-start
```

When I open the index file I just get raw Angular syntax and the pages are not showing correctly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material-start#getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run bower to get your dependencies.  Just downloading the repo is not enough.

http://bower.io/

Install bower, the in your repo run a `bower init`
You should see it grab Angular and other items needed.

Comment: yeah i've run that. But for some reason image are not showing?

Comment: Not sure on images, I see SVG files in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following command in the root directory of your git clone:

```
npm install
```

This does a bower install also. You need npm installed (packaged with [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/download/))